# String.blit vs String.sub in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Is it better to use String.blit or String.sub in OCaml? By better I mean more time- or memory-efficient or even just more idiomatic.

I.e. is it "better" to do:

```
let new_string = String.sub old_string 0 4;;
```

Or

```
String.blit old_string 0 new_string 0 4;; (* I guess new_string is a byte seq here. *)
```

Comment: They do different things!

Comment: See revision, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As those two functions have different semantics, it depends on what you want to do.

`String.blit` could indeed be used to copy part of a string into a new fresh string, but I think you should not use it instead of `sub`. First, that would be bad when you switch to OCaml 4.02 and try to use `Bytes`. Then, it makes your code way less clear (and you'd also have to add a string creation).

Also, note that `blit` is an imperative feature, whereas `sub` is itself functional. So it mainly depend on your personal programing style. In matters of performance though, they are quite comparable. That may change if the dev team decides to use a different representation for constant strings (no hurry though, it won't happen in the next few years).

Answer (score 2):

Both of them call the same function `unsafe_blit` internally. I would use whichever makes your code the clearest.

Answer (score 0):

`String.blit` allows reusing the same buffer or working with parts of buffers. If you don't need those things, just use `sub`.

In terms of complexity, both operations are linear in the size of the substring/interval.